# Is it possible to have basic wan replication for hazelcast open-source edition?

Tags: cluster-computing, replication, hazelcast, wan

I'm aware that on hazelcast editions comparison page:

https://hazelcast.com/pricing/

it is clearly specified that WAN replication is only for enterprise edition.

But, on the other hand,
this hazelcast documentation is divided into two parts:

https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/#wan

Only the second part is explicit about enterprise edition, making one assume
that the first part refers to  non enterprise edition.
I also noticed that the parameters are a bit diferent between the two parts:
(*com.hazelcast.wan.impl.WanNoDelayReplication* vs *com.hazelcast.**enterprise**.wan.replication.WanNoDelayReplication*)

I experimented a bit with hazelcast and stuff works as expected.
Only cluster replication over WAN seems to not work with opensource edition - making me thinking  that either it is completely absent in opensource edition or I messed up the configuration.

So, even I am almost sure that wan replication is exclusive for enterprise edition, I thought it would be better to ask if anyone managed to use WAN replication with opensource edition ? 
Are both editions "WAN replication" enabled while enterprise edition just has extra features ? ... or is it exclusive for enterprise ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is basic wan replication for the open source version. It only supports replication of Maps, other data structures (queues, sets, topics etc) are not replicated.
The documentation link that you've shared should be enough to make a sample.

But please don't forget that Enterprise version has more features (like support for Cache replication in addition to Map, batch replication, etc.) and actively developed.

Comment: Thanks ! I finally managed to replicate Maps over WAN with hazelcast opensource edition.

Comment: Please let us know whether we still have support for replicating only Map across **WAN** in Hazelcast 3.11 **open source edition**.

Comment: @satlearner OOB WAN replication is enterprise only now. Open source edition provides the necessary APIs to hook your own implementation though. You can create and register your own WAN endpoints (consumers and publishers), please have a look at [wan](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/tree/master/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/wan) package if you're keen to do so. `WanReplicationEndpoint` and `WanReplicationPublisher` would be the two interfaces to start with.