# Replication in hazelcast

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have a question regarding Hazelcast community edition.

If I form a cluster consisting of 2 hosts [1 in NY data center,1 in NJ data center] but in NA region only, is it possible to use replication or even for that we are required to go for Enterprise edition?

If yes, could you guide me how we can achieve that for Maps?

Thanks,
Dharam

Comment: I found something related, but not sure if still exists in latest build,                  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32505366/is-it-possible-to-have-basic-wan-replication-for-hazelcast-opensource-edition?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Hazelcast Wan Replication is available in the Community Edition but some of the fancy features are not available unless you go with Enterprise. You also lose out on Management Center to monitor the clusters. Depending on your needs you may be able to get away with Community Edition and write your own custom monitoring.